# Personal Finance Sheet - Copy and Paste Transactions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to make a personal finance sheet. I would like to take the transactions from my bank and copy and paste them into "Current Results" Table. That way I don't have to manually put them in each day. The problem I am having though is the transactions are hard to read with all the numbers and other words that I don't need.

Here is my question...

Is there a way to check the "Transactions" table and change the transactions to match what is on the items list table? (See Desired Results Table)

View example spreadsheet here.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dT7NtWysMOri9XxmYwCqJCNcL_-ZGtU0H1-BpFd3d4c/edit?usp=sharing

Another example here.

**Change - PURCHASE WENDY'S CITY STATE CARD1234 - To ---> Wendys**

Here are the formulas that I tried to get to work.

```
REGEXREPLACE(B8:B21,"something",K7:K23)

VLOOKUP(K7:K23,B8:B21,1)
```

Thanks for all of your help! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following formula

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(PROPER(B8:B21),PROPER(REGEXREPLACE(JOIN("|",G7:G),"\|+$",""))))
```

The "red words" you notice can not be extracted giving a `#N/A` error, since the sheets have no way of knowing them.
This can be remedied by adding them to the `Items List`

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [`PROPER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094133)
- [`JOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077)

Comment: Thank you Thank you!!

Comment: Glad I could help and thank you for taking the time to accept.